# Create Magento coupons progmatically with expiry dates of 30 days from now

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to Create Coupons in Magento on Action of account Create.
I have created observer which is executing properly on account Create but i am Struggling with Coupons create. I have fixed coupon names on of fixed amount on applicable on cart subtotal.

I found many ans but none of them has anything about expiry of coupon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No replies yet :(

Though I found the solution.

```
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer()->getData();
    $email = $customer['email'];
    $email100 = $email.'-100-1';
    $datei=date('d/m/Y');
    $datee = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('1 day'));
    $firstname=$customer['firstname'];
    $couponcode1=$email.'100-1';

    $data = array(
        'product_ids' => null,
        'name' => sprintf('coupon-100-1', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()),
        'description' => null,
        'is_active' => 1,
        'website_ids' => array(1),
        'customer_group_ids' => array(1),
        'coupon_type' => 2,
        'coupon_code' => $email100,
        'uses_per_coupon' => 1,
        'uses_per_customer' => 1,
        'from_date' => $datei,
        'to_date' => $datee,
        'sort_order' => null,
        'is_rss' => 1,
        'test' => 'test',
        'rule' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                            '1' =>array(
                                'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
                                'aggregator' => 'all',
                                'value' => 1,
                            ),

                            '1--1' => array(
                                'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
                                'aggregator' => 'all',
                                'value' => 1,
                            ),

                            '1--1--1' =>array(
                                'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_address',
                                'attribute' => 'base_subtotal',
                                'operator' => '>=',
                                'value' => '400'
                            ),

                            '1--1--2' =>array(
                                'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
                                'aggregator' => 'all',
                                'value' => 0
                            ),

                            '1--1--2--1' =>array(
                                'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',
                                'value' => 1,
                                'aggregator' => 'all'
                            ),

                            '1--1--2--1--1' => array(
                                'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
                                'attribute' => 'special_price',
                                'operator' => '>=',
                                'value' => 0
                            )
                        ),
            'actions' => array(
                        '1' =>array(
                            'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
                            'aggregator' => 'all',
                            'value' => 1,
                            'new_child' => null
                        ),  
                    )
                ),
        'simple_action' => 'cart_fixed',
        'discount_amount' => 100,
        'discount_qty' => 0,
        'discount_step' => null,
        'apply_to_shipping' => 0,
        'simple_free_shipping' => 0,
        'stop_rules_processing' => 0,
        'store_labels' => array()
    );
    $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
    $validateResult = $model->validateData(new Varien_Object($data));
    if ($validateResult !== true) {
            foreach($validateResult as $errorMessage) {
                // print_r($errorMessage);
                $session->addError($errorMessage);
            }
        }
        if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
            $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
        }
        if (isset($data['rule']['actions'])) {
            $data['actions'] = $data['rule']['actions'];
        }
        unset($data['rule']);
        //print_r($data);            

        $model->loadPost($data);
        $model->save();
```

Here the name of coupon code is email id followed by -100-1. 
$datei and $datee are the initial date and the expiry date. I have customized the coupon code so that it is not being used if the cart contains special price item.
Fixed amount discount is applied on the complete cart subtotal.

In Case of query do respond.